# Java - Slf4j not showing on the console :

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

I am trying to display this log.info("String is:"+str1); on the console but it doesn't show at all, how do I display log.info on the console?

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TTD {

public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> transform() {


    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

        EcrionIntegration ei = new EcrionIntegration();
        ei.setHelloWord("Hello Sharon");


        String str1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(ei);

        log.info("String is:"+str1);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

The console is displaying the attached image:

[The console without the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwVFy.png)

Answer (score 2):

It is not required to have a log4j.xml or logback.xml files for logging configuration.

**If you are importing Slf4j with Lombok,** **make sure you have the following dependencies in your pom.xml file**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a configuration file in your resources folder with STDOUT appender.

For example:

```
log4j.xml
```

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
 
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Or in `application.properties` file, eg:

```
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the below line in your XML file inside ...
ref="CONSOLE" will help to print on console.

```
        <root>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
```

Comment: Which xml file?

Comment: @san In your log4j.xml